# Error: XML content does not seem to be XML | for R version 3.3.1

Tags: r, xml

I want to read multiple xml files and write the results into CSV file.
My XMl files looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites time="430.819">
    <testsuite name="Notebook.R notebook opening as a Anonymous user" tests="8" failures="1" errors="0" time="152.319" timestamp="2016-06-27T06:22:33.708Z" package="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1">
        <testcase name="Github page has been loaded" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="22.002"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="32.666"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="5.1"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="16.111"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="5.093"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="2.058"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option clicked" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="0.028"/>
        <testcase name="Required element found hence &quot;Notebook.R&quot; notebook opened successfully" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.1.1" time="69.261">
            <failure type="assertExists">Required element found hence "Notebook.R" notebook opened successfully</failure>
        </testcase>
        <system-out></system-out>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Mini.html notebook opening as a Anonymous user" tests="8" failures="1" errors="0" time="139.257" timestamp="2016-06-27T06:22:33.710Z" package="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1">
        <testcase name="RCloud Home page already loaded" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="24.321"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="19.568"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="5.102"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="16.021"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="5.099"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="2.07"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option clicked" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="0.045"/>
        <testcase name="Required element found hence &quot;Mini.html&quot; notebook opened successfully" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.2.1" time="67.031">
            <failure type="assertExists">Required element found hence "Mini.html" notebook opened successfully</failure>
        </testcase>
        <system-out></system-out>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Shiny.html notebook opening as a Anonymous user" tests="8" failures="1" errors="0" time="139.243" timestamp="2016-06-27T06:22:33.711Z" package="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1">
        <testcase name="RCloud Home page already loaded" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="24.008"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="19.571"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="5.101"/>
        <testcase name="the element Shareable Link exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="16.104"/>
        <testcase name="Logout button exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="5.082"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option exists" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="2.063"/>
        <testcase name="Fork option clicked" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="0.017"/>
        <testcase name="Required element found hence &quot;shiny.html&quot; notebook opened successfully" classname="anonymous_user/tc_52.3.1" time="67.297">
            <failure type="assertExists">Required element found hence "shiny.html" notebook opened successfully</failure>
        </testcase>
        <system-out></system-out>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

and below is the R script

```
# Script to Parse the XMLfiles
# install.packages("XML")
library("XML")
path = "File path" # set the location of xml files
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".xml")

print(file.names)
D=data.frame("Package", 'Name',"Time", "Failures",'Status')
for (k in 1:length(file.names))
{
doc<-xmlTreeParse(file.names[k])
top<-xmlRoot(doc)
z=names(top)
testcases<-length(z)
package=c()
name=c()
failures=c()
time=c()
for (i in 1:length(z))
{
b<-xmlAttrs(top[[i]])
package=c(package,b['package'])
name=c(name,b['name'])
failures=c(failures, b['failures'])
time=c(time,b['time'])
}
status=c()
df<-data.frame(package, name, time, failures)
status<-function(val){
    if (val == 0 ){
        status=c(status,'Pass')
    }
    else{
        status=c(status,'Fail')
    }
}
lapply(list(df['failures']), status)

status<-function(val){
    if (val != 0 ){
        return ('Fail')
    }
    else{
        return ('Pass')
    }
}
status<-apply(df['failures'],1,FUN= status)
df<-cbind(df,status)
D=rbind(as.matrix(D),as.matrix(df))
print(df)
}
# warnings()
write.csv(file="result.csv",D)
```

when i run the above R scripts it shows the following error:

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: '1st xml file name from the directory'

**Note:** All the XML files are present on my local machine and R version is 3.3.1 and also i have installed the required package.

Since i am new to R please help me